# How can I isolate index segments based upon linearity using R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a vector of start times for individual sweeps of a number of protocols performed throughout an experiment, and I want to isolate the protocols based upon the linearity of each sweep start time. Plotting the vector makes it clear which sweeps are sequential, but I'm not sure how to separate each protocol based upon the linearity of the start times.

```
starting_times = c(1518.280, 1523.622, 1529.188, 1534.527, 1539.858, 1545.006, 1550.458, 1555.838, 1561.153, 1566.463, 1571.848, 1577.106, 1582.271, 1587.658, 1592.874, 1598.086, 1603.334, 1608.481, 1613.953, 1619.115, 1673.661, 1695.512, 1716.557, 1856.711, 1866.470, 1869.777, 1873.147, 1886.839, 1890.145, 1893.404, 1896.853, 1900.199, 1903.585, 1921.432, 1931.714, 1937.140, 1942.540, 1947.849, 1953.022, 1958.291, 1963.643, 1968.793, 2008.844, 2020.818, 2029.011, 2044.400, 2053.175, 2077.344)

plot(starting_times)
```

[image: starting_times]

Comment: However many break points the data requires. Each protocol runs for `n` sweeps, but unfortunately there is no set standard for number of sweeps per protocol. I'm hoping I can develop a reliable way to separate each protocol based upon sweep interval, which will be consistent within protocols. This could tell me if a sweep is part of a protocol, and whether a new protocol has started.

Comment: Yes, the method below is very practical.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm going to try to apply a few other variables, and make the methodology shown below an element of the overall sorting process.

Comment: I reckon it's possible. How would you like me to contribute. I can provide data similar to what I'd shown you previously.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so obvious in this example which points belong to which sweep. I'm guessing there are 6 clusters, but the very last point doesn't fit well with the last cluster, and almost looks like it's the start of the next cluster.

To label all points according to how well they fit linearly with the previous point, you could define a function like this:

```r
groupify <- function(x, threshold = 10) {

  for(i in seq(length(x) - 1)) {
    if(i == 1) {
      group <- 1
      last_grad <- diff(x)[i]
      new_group <- FALSE
      next
    }
    if((abs(diff(x)[i] - last_grad) < threshold) | new_group) {
      group <- c(group, tail(group, 1))
      new_group <- FALSE
    }  else {
      group <- c(group, tail(group, 1) + 1)
      new_group <- TRUE
    }
    last_grad <- diff(x)[i]
  }

  setNames(data.frame(seq_along(x), x, factor(c(1, group))),
           c("index", deparse(substitute(x)), "group"))
}
```

We can test this out by plotting the clusters in ggplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(groupify(starting_times), 
       aes(index, starting_times, color = group)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

You can see it has correctly identified all the points into the correct sweep (perhaps apart from the last point, since it is poorly aligned with the preceding sequence). You can play around with the threshold to detect more or less groups, but that last point is always going to be an outlier - the gradient changes more here than it does between some of the obvious sweeps, so you might need to manually relabel it.